# "No such file or directory" when including SFML/Graphics.hpp from a header file

Tags: c++, header, sfml

Everything compiles fine when I include this particular .hpp in a header in a test project I made with identical (copy-pasted) project settings (include path, linker path etc.). For some reason however, my project won't compile when trying to include it from a file deep in my header hierarchy. Headers have guards.

Here's the log:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C ""C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile"

"----------Building project:[ Rogue - Debug ]----------"

mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'E:/CPP/Rogue/Rogue'
codelite-cc "C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/g++.exe" -g -O0 -std=c++17 -std=c++14 -std=c++11 -Wall     Char.cpp   -o Char
In file included from Item.h:7:0, //this says ' #include "Entity.h" '
                 from Char.h:12, //this says ' #include "Item.h" '
                 from Char.cpp:1:
Entity.h:5:29: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Char] Error 1
<builtin>: recipe for target 'Char' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/CPP/Rogue/Rogue'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
====3 errors, 1 warnings====
```

And here is my [header "hierarchy"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7heT.png). (A.h -> B.h means that A #includes B)

defs.h and utils.h are irrelevant class-wise (they contain #defines and utility functions respectively.)

My compiler settings:

[Compiler](https://%20i.imgur.com/9DvVWWN.png)

[Linker](https://%20i.imgur.com/Q6mMwlw.png)

SFML is installed in E:/CPP/Libs/SFML

The project is in E:/CPP/Rogue

No enviroment variable as far as I'm aware.

Comment: show your code may be more clear on your question

Comment: Probably you're using relative paths somewhere, and they're different depending on test project and main project. Hard to say without more information

Comment: It's spread among 21 files, but sure. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a7rqmp5rb1gh791/AABLlVs1V8hXRYqfCkJXQ2EGa?dl=0

@AndyG Every include is either <> to a basic header (like string or vector), <> to SFML/.. or "" to a local header (same folder)

Comment: @DavidN: I don't want to look at the entire project. Perhaps you can compose a small reproducible example. a [MCVE] provide your compiler settings, your filesystem layout (what's relevant, e.g. where SFML is installed to vs where you code is), your project settings, perhaps even environment variables. Questions like this are usually difficult to debug via stackoverflow because they rely so heavily on what your environment looks like.

Comment: @AndyG Fair enough, problem is I tried (in that test project) to replicate the bug and I couldn't find it.

My compiler settings:

https://i.imgur.com/9DvVWWN.png //Compiler
https://i.imgur.com/Q6mMwlw.png //Linker

SFML is installed in E:/CPP/Libs/SFML
The project is in E:/CPP/Rogue

No enviroment variable as far as I'm aware. 

Keep in mind these settings are the exact same in the project that compiles.

Comment: @DavidN: Comments on SO are transient; please place the relevant information into the question itself.

Comment: @AndyG You're right, my bad.

Comment: Something's weird in your setup. I think you have an issue with your IDE, or you have a mixup of settings. If you look at the compiler invocation in your log you have `codelite-cc "C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/g++.exe" -g -O0 -std=c++17 -std=c++14 -std=c++11 -Wall     Char.cpp   -o Char`. There are _no_ include paths given at all. Hence g++ will only search the standard library and in your project directory.